# How to Collect all Product List from Flipkart API

Tags: e-commerce, flipkart-api

I am new to Flipkart API, and I need to collect all presented product list from Flipkart but I am not able to find any API which provide the all presented list.

Comment: Do you mean you want a list of all the products you've got listed, as a seller? Looking at https://seller.flipkart.com/api-docs/listing-api-docs/LMAPIRef.html that seems to only be possible if you know the IDs of the listed items, and put them into the request (see https://seller.flipkart.com/api-docs/listing-api-docs/LMAPIRef.html#get-listings-v3-sku-ids). It seems they will assume you know the IDs of your items, and/or that your system recorded the ID generated when you create a listing through the API

Comment: @ADyson Yes I need all listing which has been listed by the seller. I don't have any sku id's. I am creating an API which collect the all isting present on single seller, Their is not such document or API mentioned by Flipkart. Thanks for your Reply.

Comment: Well if it isn't documented, then it probably isn't possible. Perhaps you can ask Flipkart for confirmation

Comment: @ADyson Okay, Thank's for your reply. Yes already emailed them for listing let's see what happens